# Gathering multi gwt modules to one war

Tags: gwt, maven

I have project with multi module structure, like this

```
root
|
core
  |
  core-services
  |
  core-gwt-ui
|
some-like-core-modules
|
root-war
```

**root-war** this is module to compress all other modules *jars* to one *.war*.
When maven builds **core-gwt-ui** I'll got **webapp** dir in *src.main*. With another modules is the same story.

So, How to tune *root-war.pom* to collect all gwt build results in to one **war**?

Here is my maven plugin configuration to build **core-gwt-ui**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <inplace>true</inplace>
        <runTarget>sample.client.Sample25/Sample25.html</runTarget>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Either you *gwt:compile* your apps in each project, in which case they'd better be WARs that you use a overlays in *root-war*
2. or you simply package the sources and classes and do a big *gwt:compile* within *root-war*.